Transform column data into row data in oracle sql
I have a table called customers which contains customers account details like month, account, inactive_accs.
Table:



Month
accounts
inactive_accs




2023-11-01
2500
310


2023-12-01
2900
260


2024-01-01
3500
320


2024-02-01
3200
300


2024-03-01
3850
350


2024-04-01
4200
380



Expected output:

First column(2023) should contain last year's(2023) total values of accounts & inactive_accs .

For inactive_accs every month's value are to be added until the years end.(ex. Jan-24+Feb-24+Mar-24=Mar-24 value).

Last column(2024) contains total values of accounts & inactive_accs upto the month/year end.






2023
Jan-24
Feb-24
Mar-24
Apr-24
2024




Accounts
5400
3500
3200
3850
4200
14000


inactive_accs
570
320
620
970
1350
1350



When a new month comes output of report will be




2023
Jan-24
Feb-24
Mar-24
Apr-24
May-24
2024




Accounts
5400
3500
3200
3850
4200
[Accounts of MAY]
[14000+May]


inactive_accs
570
320
620
970
1350
[Total+May]
[Total+May]




I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

What happens when you get a new month?  Generally speaking, I'd suggest handling pivots like this in your reporting tool.

@marc_s I have added tags but it got removed in edit suggestion. I am adding again.

Since you didnt include the type of database, I was able to do this with MySQL

SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(accounts) FROM customers WHERE YEAR(Month) = 2023) AS "2023",
   
    (SELECT SUM(inactive_accs) FROM customers WHERE YEAR(Month) = 2024 AND MONTH(Month) <= 1) AS "Jan-24",
    (SELECT SUM(inactive_accs) FROM customers WHERE YEAR(Month) = 2024 AND MONTH(Month) <= 2) AS "Feb-24",
    (SELECT SUM(inactive_accs) FROM customers WHERE YEAR(Month) = 2024 AND MONTH(Month) <= 3) AS "Mar-24",
    (SELECT SUM(inactive_accs) FROM customers WHERE YEAR(Month) = 2024 AND MONTH(Month) <= 4) AS "Apr-24",
    
    (SELECT SUM(accounts) FROM customers WHERE YEAR(Month) = 2024) AS "2024"
FROM customers
LIMIT 1;

Output:



2023
Jan-24
Feb-24
Mar-24
Apr-24
2024




5400
3500
6700
10350
14200
14000



Each column shows the respective values for the total of 2023, cumulative totals for each month in 2024, and the final total for 2024.

I have added the code for Oracle.

monthly_data and yearly_data CTE extracts the month and year for each account and inactive accounts
cumulative_inactive_data calculates the cumulative sum for inactive account from January 2024 till current month.

Fiddle
with monthly_data as (
    select 
        to_char(month, 'yyyy-mm') as month,
        extract(year from month) as year,
        accounts,
        inactive_accs
    from customers
),
yearly_data as (
    select 
        extract(year from month) as year,
        sum(accounts) as total_accounts_2023,
        sum(inactive_accs) as total_inactive_accs_2023
    from customers
    where extract(year from month) = 2023
    group by extract(year from month)
),
cumulative_inactive_data as (
    select 
        month,
        inactive_accs,
        sum(inactive_accs) over (partition by extract(year from to_date(month, 'yyyy-mm')) order by month rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as cumulative_inactive_accs
    from monthly_data
    where year = 2024
)
select 
    'accounts' as metric,
    (select total_accounts_2023 from yearly_data) as "2023",
    max(case when month = '2024-01' then accounts end) as "jan-24",
    max(case when month = '2024-02' then accounts end) as "feb-24",
    max(case when month = '2024-03' then accounts end) as "mar-24",
    max(case when month = '2024-04' then accounts end) as "apr-24",
    max(case when month = '2024-05' then accounts end) as "may-24",
    (select sum(accounts) from monthly_data where year = 2024) as "2024"
from monthly_data
where year = 2024
group by 'accounts'
union all
select 
    'inactive_accs' as metric,
    (select total_inactive_accs_2023 from yearly_data) as "2023",
    max(case when month = '2024-01' then inactive_accs end) as "jan-24",
    max(case when month = '2024-02' then cumulative_inactive_accs end) as "feb-24",
    max(case when month = '2024-03' then cumulative_inactive_accs end) as "mar-24",
    max(case when month = '2024-04' then cumulative_inactive_accs end) as "apr-24",
    max(case when month = '2024-05' then cumulative_inactive_accs end) as "may-24",
    (select sum(inactive_accs) from cumulative_inactive_data) as "2024"
from cumulative_inactive_data
group by 'inactive_accs'
order by metric;

Output

